# Is the .Net 4.0 Runtime supported in SSRS + Sql Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In the upcoming release of Sql Server 2008 R2 (aka Sql Server 2010) can I write:

a) SSRS Extensions (eg Custom Authentication) against the .Net 4.0 runtime?

b) Sql Server CLR procedures in .Net 4.0?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

It appears not according to [a post by Doug Holland](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/10/16/sql-server-2008-sqlclr-net-framework-version/).

[Work does appear to be happening](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2009/12/09/sql-server-express-and-net-4.aspx) to ensure that SQL 2008 (Express at least) will install on a machine with .NET 4.0, but even then it still only uses the 2.0 CLR.